# Using Microsoft Graph can you access tasks and events updated on outlook.live.com?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I have followed the documents on sites:

I. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/get-started/android#call-microsoft-graph-using-the-microsoft-graph-rest-api

II. and I have the understanding of differences between Microsoft and Office 365 based accounts:

http://www.brucebnews.com/2013/04/the-difference-between-a-microsoft-account-and-an-office-365-account/

III. Now when I login using my non-office (personal Microsoft) account that is, for example, a hotmail.com account. I can use it to login at:
login.live.com and outlook.live.com.

I can access and update Tasks and Calendar Events.

IV. The authority URL that is set on Microsoft Graph is https://login.microsoftonline.com/common

And I know that to login at this site I need Office 365 account, that is subscribed to use MS Office on a monthly or yearly basis. But anyways I see that I can sign in using my Hotmail account in Microsoft Graph API.

V. From the Microsoft Graph, though I can sign into my Hotmail account, but it doesn't return authentication code. Instead, there is a response that I get:

{"type":0,"errorDescription":"Network error","code":3}

My question is that is there a right way of accessing Tasks, Calendar from outlook.live.com using Microsoft Graph or any? Because while I had a one-month free subscription, I could access events and tasks from outlook.office.com using my Microsoft account using the same Graph. I get access token well.

I had to just change my permissions and URLS to be able to access.

Comment: All of a sudden the apis can start access the records from outlook.live.com, whether it is task or event, even when the APIs are for outlook.office.com graph. I think Microsoft was upgrading it's system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me see if I can use this site to sign up at login.live.com and get any authentication, access code that I can use to access calendar at outlook.live.com.

I shall update here if I can find some other API to independently access the above.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243647.aspx

[I found lately that the liveconnect APIs are obsolete, we can use if it is using IMAP with OAUTH2 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826535.aspx]

Edit: The APIs have start working with any account and any site "office" or "liveconnect". Please do not bother now.